# Can a wondrous item be used to make a scroll?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

Since some magic items (scrolls, wands, potions) require the spell must be provided in order to be made but its less picky about how the spell is provided, for example could boots of speed be used to provide haste to create a scroll of haste?

Answer (score 2):

> A spell prerequisite may be provided by a character who has prepared the spell (or who knows the spell, in the case of a sorcerer or bard), **or through the use of a spell completion or spell trigger magic item or a spell-like ability that produces the desired spell effect.** For each day that passes in the creation process, the creator must expend one spell completion item or one charge from a spell trigger item if either of those objects is used to supply a prerequisite.

From the rules explaining [the magic item description format](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Descriptions), in the section about requirements. As *boots of speed* are not a spell-completion or spell-trigger item, they cannot be used to create another magic item, like a *scroll of haste*.

Since a scroll **is** a spell-completion item, several *scrolls of haste* could be used to produce *boots of speed*. This would be fantastically expensive and is not recommended.

Note that you can ignore a magic item’s spell requirement with a Spellcraft check.

Comment: For scrolls, potions, and wands you cant ignore the spell, it must be provided which has been the source of my issue. MT so I dont learn new spells on leveling and we arnt coming across scrolls and weve failed to get every enemy wizards spellbook weve come across

Comment: @Fering “MT so I dont learn new spells on leveling” is an absolutely atrocious ruling; my sympathies. Unfortunately, your reaction to that should have been “ok, I guess I’m playing mystic theurge in some other game.” Or to just write off mystic theurge entirely...

Comment: No. The increase to his spellcasting level does not grant any other benefits, except for spells per day, spells known (for spontaneous casters), and an increase to his overall caster level. He must spend time and gold to add new spells to his spellbook. Taken from the FAQ on the MT page on d20

Comment: @Fering I don’t care who made the ruling: it’s terrible, and personally I wouldn’t play under a GM who ruled that way—they clearly do not understand the game well enough to run a game I would enjoy. The mystic theurge spellcasting boilerplate was copied directly from 3.5e to Pathfinder, and in both editions was almost-certainly copy-pasted without all that much care paid; to rule so negatively over what is most probably an oversight, in a case where you are already dealing with a badly underpowered option, indicates that the one so ruling doesn’t know the game well at all.

Comment: Since its really only wizards who are affected as divine spellcasters always have full access to their list and spontaneous also learn their spells. Wizards frequently learn new spells by encountering them, deciphering them, and adding them to their own. My biggest issue is that Im not really coming across any spells to learn.

Comment: For your last comment, I assume you mean you can ignore the spell for anything but scrolls, potions, and wands, right? Because thats how my group understands the rules but if youve got evidence otherwise Id love to read it